# Ajax Security and code-behind functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

**EDIT:** I know you should never trust client side... My question is what can I use to validate since at the current moment I'm expecting three parameters two of which rely on the client side form (registration email, and email message)

I'm probably going about this the wrong way but it seems like Ajax isn't very secure (well duh..It's client side..) How would you go about creating a function so it cannot be called Via the console by intruders?

So let's say I have a function called SendMail that accepts the to,message and from parameters in which it sends an ajax request to the code behind to send the email.

what can I add that would prevent you from opening the console, recreating my function (except with literal variables ) and executing it via the console?

Code Behind:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Shared Sub sendMail(subject As String, userEmail As String(), message As String)
    Dim fromEmail As String = "supah@domain.com"
    Dim fromAbrv As String = "hidden Tiger"
    Try
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("server.domain")
        mail.From = New MailAddress(fromEmail, fromAbrv)
        For i As Integer = 0 To userEmail.Length - 1
            mail.[To].Add(userEmail(i))
        Next
        mail.Subject = subject
        mail.Body = message
        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        smtp.Send(mail)
    Catch exc As Exception
        Throw exc
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't stop this so you should validate your inputs on the server.

Comment: Never trust the client side.

Comment: but I have 3 inputs... I can't validate a message nor the To email address

Comment: What is it you are trying to prevent?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent someone from being able to access the site and send emails by overwritting the variables/function via the console.

Comment: simply don't make it possible server-side. there is nothing you can do client-side to stop it.

Comment: how would I make it not possible via server-side? I'm looking for a server side solution

Comment: Don't allow your server-side code to accept too many parameters. Only accept the bare minimum then compose a valid message on the server.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent? narrow it down. Are you trying to prevent someone from having your server spam someone else? from what you've posted so far, i don't think that's really possible other than ensuring that you don't send the email to the same address twice.

Comment: you got it kevin! I want to prevent someone from spaming someone else via my email function!

Comment: What does this form do? is it a user sign-up form?

Comment: Yes, this code is being used by my company in all of it's pages so the forgot password page uses it too. making it incredibly easy for the hacker to add his name in the To array sending both the customer and the hacker a reset password link. we've also had instances where a hacker logged in to our site, found our function and changed it so it send other people an email through our servers

Comment: Don't accept a `To` parameter nor a message. It is internal so you can determine that on the server. And the `From` address should be validated as Kevin's answer outlines. In this way your server can't be used as a generic email service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure your registration process in a way that prevents this up front.

First, when the registration form is submitted to the server, check for an existing user with that email address. If one exists, return an error message.

If the user doesn't exist, create a new record for the user and flag it as not activated. Next, send the user a registration email with a url that when clicked, activates the account. **Do not include any of the information from the original form in this email!**

with it setup that way, the most any malicious user can do is send a single activation email to someone.

As far as the reset password form, it shouldn't be possible to use it to send emails to users other than the existing user because you should check the email address in the database, then use the one from the database rather than from the form. Additionally, you should never send the password in an email, instead send a link in an email that sends the user to a page where they can enter a new password.

Comment: mind you this is the Forgot Password not reset password. The forgot password will assume the user is unable to authenticate

Comment: Right, but it shouldn't be any different. You check the email against the database for an exact match, if a user record is found, send an email to that user with a link that will take them to a page where they can change their password. You should use the email address from the database to send the email rather than the one from the form.

Comment: If a user is using that to spam, throttle it. Only allow one password reset request per hour.

Comment: I think I see what your getting at. so are you saying that the sendEmail function shouldn't be called by Ajax? I have a javascript function that calls the code behind function a user can type in his name and a message (which would end up being stripped) and send it to whom ever he wants (his buddies, mom, neighbhor, etc..)

Comment: BAM! throttling is definitely one way to go!

Comment: If the email address doesn't match a user in teh database, why would it send an email? and what is "message" for with a forgotten password form?

Comment: sorry, I switched back to the registration form. so what the previous developer did is create a javascript template that sends variables to the code-behind which sends an email to the user based on those javascript variables (To email and message) if I go in the console and type in SendMail("randomGuy@comcast.net","hahahaha I'm spamming you!") it would send that email

Comment: Haha, yeah, get rid of that. Emails should be in reaction to a server-side process, at most you should only be able to request an action to happen, such as registering a new user or resetting a password that may or may not result in an email depending on the validity of the data sent.

Comment: Yea.. I think i'm gonna have to re-do that. I was just hoping there was something out there but I guess not! Thanks for the help! you get the answer because you've been the most helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot trust your clientside code to prevent the client from anything at all. Never ever trust the client. Treat every single request as tampered with and malicious.

Even if you managed to "protect" that function, an attacker could just fake the whole request.

Validate your parameters serverside.

Comment: Which parameters could I validate? the to address can be anything since our users have a multitude of different email addresses, the from can be forced server side, but the message has to come from the client side

Comment: Don't let the client send the "to" address, let the client only send the target user's ID and find the mail serverside. Strip HTML tags and links from the message. It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: the "To" address comes from an email text box field that the user fills out upon registration. so does the message

Comment: So... you want the user to send a mail to himself?

Comment: *sigh.. The user puts in his email (which is not held in our servers as of yet) when the user submits the form, it calls a separate function that builds a message for the user "Thank you for registering" and pushes it out to the send mail code behind function. and then it sends an email to our customer center team notifying them that X user has just registered with the form information they filled out

Comment: So why would you need the client to supply the message body?

Comment: the message body is built by a compilation of other text fields. the user gets a confirmation email with the information they've entered in the text fields. same with the customer center folks

Comment: Then just send the other text fields, validate them (strip tags/htmlspecialchars, length), compose the message serverside.

Comment: if I were to compose the message server side, what can stop the hacker from rebuilding the function via console and adding his email address in the to field and creating his own message via the text boxes (with all html stripped out)?

Comment: How are they going to re-build it in the console if it's on the server?

Comment: You need to put some time and effort into fully understanding the concept of clientside and serverside code. Let the user send whatever he wants, clientside tampering doesn't matter if you check everything serverside.

Comment: I understand the concept... thus my search for a server-side solution to prevent this